# What is between air molecules?

Tags: vacuum

I understand that all gases are fast moving and have space between them, but what exactly is this "space"? Surely there must be something in there. Can it be just plain vacuum? I was thinking that since atoms are 99% empty space, it could just be them that are taking up the space in between

Comment: Is 'plain vacuum' actually 'something'? This is a very confused question.

Comment: @Axop51 Then what do you think is in the 99% empty space of the atoms?

Comment: @Hasan Vacuum, I'm guessing?

Answer (score 1):

In classical physics, the answer is "nothing."

In quantum physics, the question doesn't really mean anything, because there is usually no way to know the "exact" position of an elementary particle in any case.

But the OP's thought that "surely there must be something in there" has quite a long history - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horror_vacui_(physics).

Comment: Wrong. In quantum physics you can imagine measuring all particles in a gas with all their positions. You don’t know they velocity but that is another story. And when you measure these particles positions what is in between. That is a question.